# Can't figure out why overloaded operator[] isn't getting called

Tags: c++, pointers, operator-overloading

I got a class `Matrix` and a class `Row`. `Matrix` has as member variable a pointer to a pointer of an object from class `Row`. I overloaded the operator [] for `Matrix` and `Row`. But somehow the overloaded operator from `Row` is never getting called and I can't figure out why not.

Example Code:
matrix.h

```
class Row
{
    int* value;
    int size;

public:
    int& operator[](int i)
    {
        assert(i >= 0 && i < size);
        return value[i];
    }
};
class Matrix
{
private:
    Row **mat;        // Pointer to "Row"-Vector
    int nrows, ncols;   // Row- and Columnnumber

public:
    Row& Matrix::operator[](int i){
        assert(i >= 0 && i < nrows);
        return *mat[i];
    }
    Row** getMat() {
        return mat;
    }
    // Constructor
    Matrix(int rows, int cols, int value);

};
```

matrix.cpp

```
#include "matrix.h"

Matrix::Matrix(int rows, int cols, int value) : nrows(rows), ncols(cols){
    mat = new Row*[rows];

    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        mat[i] = new Row(ncols);
        for(int j = 0; j < ncols; j++){
            // the operator-overload of Row[] isn't getting called and I don't get why not
            mat[i][j] = value;
        }
    }
}


int main(){

Matrix m = new Matrix(2, 2, 4);

return 0;
```

Comment: Does ```Matrix::operator``` compile?

Comment: `mat[i] = new Row(ncols);` and `mat[i][j] = value;` it will not compile. Please post [mcve]

Comment: mat[i] = new Row(ncols); is not correct either. Mat[i] returns reference to Row, 
Row class does not have constructor either.

So I would
1. add constructor to Row class
2. remove Matrix::operator with just Row& operator[]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I just figured it out myself. 
I tried to call the []-operator from `Matrix` through `mat[][]`, but since `mat` is a `Row**` `Row& Matrix::operator[](int i)` is never getting called.

Answer (score 1):

`mat[i]` gives you `Row*`, and you want to call `Row::operator[]`, but pointer to `Row` is not dereferenced automatically. So you have to dereference it manually: `(*mat[i])[j]`.